# Why does email be sent locally and not through server?

Tags: django, email, passwords

I'm working on a Django application.
I have set up all my required password reset views and corresponding pages.
In the final step I want to use Send Grid in my application to send the emails. I have the following setting s in my base.py file

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'codesniper99' # email id
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '****' #password
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

where **** is my password for the username codesniper99 on sendgrid.com

But when I use the password reset function I get locally generated email to my account. Like when i put email for reset as `akhilvaid21@gmail.com`

I get this:

[image: email]

when I push my code to my production server and not local host then it doesn't work and no email is sent. What am I doing wrong?

Also how do I change the name of webmaster@localhost???

Comment: Have you checked the logs in sendgrid? What do they say about sending the mail?

Comment: where are the logs?

Comment: I don't have my SendGrid account now in hand but there should be a mail sending log in the sendgrid UI somewhere. Look for Email activity. It it this: https://app.sendgrid.com/email_activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set [`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#default-from-email) and [`SERVER_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#server-email) in your settings.

Many email providers will only let you send email from verified email addresses. It looks as if Sendgrid might be blocking emails because Django is using the default `webmaster@localhost` for `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`.